# ¿Como una tabla con dos consultas de condiciones contrarias?

Tags: sql-server

Resulta ser que quiero mostrar en una consulta la cantidad de facturas efectivas(Es decir facturas que no están anuladas) y al mismo tiempo la cantidad de facturas anuladas, sin embargo no puedo usar la sentencia **where** debido a que para saber si estan o no anuladas se basan en un mismo campo llamado "Anulada". Intente aplicar entonces esto

```
SELECT
co_ven as Codigo,
(Select top 1 ven_des from vendedor where factura.co_ven = vendedor.co_ven) as Vendedor,
case when(anulada)= 'FALSE' then(count (fact_num)) END AS FACT_EFECT,
case when(anulada)= 'True' then(count (fact_num)) END AS FACT_ANULADA,
sum(tot_neto) as Ventas_Efectivas

from factura
group by co_ven, anulada
order by Fact_efect
```

Y el resultado "funciona" pero no como yo quisiera pues me arroja lo siguiente.

```
Codigo  Vendedor                                                        Efect   Anu Total_neto
151     ANNERYS PEREZ                                                   NULL    7   486959.00
205     NORELYS PETIT                                                   NULL    12  9111599.55
209     GLIVER MARTINEZ                                                 NULL    37  37871045.35
233     FRANCIS AVILA                                                   NULL    85  59434374.81
424     RUBXIRIS REYES                                                  NULL    22  323294217.17
434     ADRIANA SMITH                                                   NULL    7   0.00
439     ISABEL MAVO                                                     NULL    6   0.00
117     ABRAHAM PINEDA                                                  1   NULL    15000.00
040     NADIA FALCON                                                    1   NULL    1775300.00
328     JHINS DELGADO                                                   1   NULL    6600000.00
039     DANIELA SUAREZ                                                  1   NULL    4800.00
026     GIORARDIX MARIN                                                 1   NULL    626580.00
03      CAJA 03                                                         1   NULL    851780.00
14      CAJA 14                                                         1   NULL    958700.00
```

Se me repiten los vendedores, uno con las faturas anuladas, y otro con las facturas efectivas. Quiera que mostrara una unica fila con las facturas efectivas y al mismo tiempo, las facturas anuladas.

Comment: ¿La respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias mejoras que hacerle a tu código, pero la principal probablemente es esa subquery que estás haciendo para obtener el vendedor (que deberías usar un `JOIN`). Ahora, para que tu agrupación resulte como quieres, tienes que mover el `COUNT` hacia afuera del `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
    f.co_ven Codigo,
    v.ven_des Vendedor,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN anulada = 'False' THEN fact_num END) FACT_EFECT,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN anulada = 'True' THEN fact_num END) FACT_ANULADA,
    SUM(tot_neto) Ventas_Efectivas
FROM dbo.factura f
INNER JOIN dbo.vendedor v
    ON f.co_ven = v.co_ven
GROUP BY 
    f.CO_VEN, v.ven_des
ORDER BY Fact_efect 
;
```

Comment: @Marcos toda la razón sobre el alias. Sobre la subconsulta, son notoriamente de peor performance que joins, por qué piensas que sería más óptimo como estaba?

Comment: Supongamos que son `10` vendedores y `1.000.000` de facturas, la memoria que requiere el producto cartesiano de unir ambas tablas es superior a que simplemente ejecutar `10` sub-consultas para 10 registros (_resultado del `GROUP BY`_). Igual no estoy seguro que así sea el funcionamiento, habría que hacer un `BENCHMARK`

Comment: @Marcos es que no funciona así. Si ves el select original, el `FROM` es la tabla `factura`, y sobre eso va un `SELECT TOP 1 .... FROM vendedor`. Si tomamos tu ejemplo, tiene que hacer ese `TOP 1` 10.000.000 de veces

Comment: Mira [esta demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fxq75jpKbWjJwwpfNPKr3i/1), se puede ver que la sub-consulta solo se ejecuta `x` veces, donde `x` es la cantidad de vendedores y NO la cantidad de facturas.

Comment: @Marcos pero esa consulta es en MySQL y no es necesariamente equivalente a la subconsulta creada en SQL Server

Comment: En SQL Server es igual, si tenes un IDE, lo podes ver en el "Plan de Ejecución", primero se ejecuta el GROUP BY y luego para cada registro se ejecuta la sub-consulta. Igual, estoy de acuerdo que las sub-consultas no son lo mejor, pero en este caso particular, me inclino a pensar que si. Mas [info acá](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)